# Unwanted spacing below image

Tags: html, css, spacing

I'm trying to create a fixed-position footer at the bottom of my page. but there's an issue with spacing below the image and the bottom of the viewpoint that is unwanted:

Base Image:

[image: base]

The Issue:

[image: issue]

The padding below the image is unwanted.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="containerBarKonge">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="./kongelogo.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#containerBarKonge {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#containerBarKonge > ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    min-width: 1053px;
    background-color: #900;
}
#containerBarKonge > ul * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding in a `img { padding:0px; }` in your CSS?

Comment: its padding and margin are set to 0 via the last rule from above.

Comment: Ah.. I gotcha. crush's answer seems to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the vertical align to bottom on the image:

```
#containerBarKonge img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

Comment: Thank you. that did it. I have to wait to upvote (for 10 minutes) but when its accessible, will do

Comment: This may solve this issue but IMHO it is a hack. Vertical-align should not be employed in lists.

Comment: @ProfileTwist How is it a hack? He wanted it to be aligned at the bottom...read the question.

Comment: @crush +1 because you DID solve the question. However, I think it is more important to provide insight on the inner workings of CSS and why something may not working then just "here take this - it works." `vertical-align` is not as much as a "hack" per se but a severe limitation in positioning because it forces the content to the bottom. There is no possibility for adjustment.

Comment: The OP wanted it at the bottom, though...he could still adjust it by adding padding to it's container...

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the image having a default property of "display: inline;" - which is the equivalent to saying "have this image run along like text."

Images should rarely be employed as inline containers. Instead, an image should be defined as either display: `block` or `inline-block`. This gives you much precise control over your iamges versus - just align this to the top or bottom. What if you want the image 1px from the bottom? With `vertical-align` you can not.

So the solution is to do the following:

```
#containerBarKonge > ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20px; /* or however tall it is */
}
#containerBarKong > ul li img {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Assuming it is 18px tall and you want it at the bottom: 20 - 18 = 2px */
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

there you go. You have PRECISe control of the positioning of the image while it retains its ability to run along like text.

Comment: This isn't the same thing at all. Look at these two fiddles [inline](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzabx/) vs [inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzabx/1/). He wanted the image at the bottom of the container. You'd have to set some absolute positioning after turning it into a block element.